# SQL Multiple int query as parameter

Tags: sql, list, stored-procedures

**Code**

```
Create Table TestTable(
   prop1 int, 
   prop2 int
)

insert into TestTable values (1,5)
insert into TestTable values (2,3)
insert into TestTable values (3,5)
insert into TestTable values (4,3)
insert into TestTable values (5,5)
```

**Situation**

I've created this small test just to use as an example but it is similar to what I want.

The situation is that I have a stored procedure like this:

```
create procedure TestProc
   @TestParamater <type> 
as
begin
     select * from TestTable where prop1 in @TestParameter
```

**Problem**

What type should the parameter be to support the following query:

```
exec TestProc (select prop1 from TestTable where prop2 = 5) -- resulting in 3 prop1's
```

Is this possible without the use of temp tables or user defined tables?

If not, how can I use this (with using a temp table) but still inside a query...

As in:

```
select * 
from TestTable 
where prop1 in (insert and select everything that's in the temptable)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can *Dynamic SQL* inside stored procedures,

```
Create Procedure TestProc
    @sqlQuery NVarchar(4000)   
AS
    Declare @inQuery AS NVarchar(4000)
    SET @inQuery = 'SELECT * FROM TestTable where prop1 in (' + @sqlQuery + ')' 
    EXECUTE(@inQuery)
GO
```

usage,

```
EXEC TestProc ('select prop1 from TestTable where prop2=5')
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just pass prop2 to your stored procedure as an int?

Something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TestTable 
WHERE prop1 IN (SELECT prop1 FROM TestTable WHERE prop2=5)
```

or actually:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TestTable 
WHERE prop1 IN (SELECT prop1 FROM TestTable WHERE prop2=@prop2)
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86ba2/1).

Good luck.

Comment: My bad for missing it in the example, but in my program the prop2 values are not the same. Meaning, there is a possibility to get 2 rows with different of which both id's need to be send to the procedure

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you want with a single type, unless you use dynamic SQL.  In that case, you would pass in the list as a comma-separated list.

You *could* put the list in as a string, so the resulting query would use something like:

```
where ','+@TestParameter+',' like '%,'+cast(prop1 as varchar(255))+',%'
```

This would give the same effect as the `in`.  You would have to concatenate the values together to make the string argument.

The second query, I just do not understand.  What do you mean "insert and select everything in the temp table"?  Just load the temp table first and then use it in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not put the whole thing inside your sp and supply prop2 instead of prop1?